# when clicked on high to low price should change

Tags: php, mysql

Want to sort price by `cat_id` when clicked on product from dropdown category product will 
open in results.php page, when clicked on high to low it is showing no product in 
database.

**function.php**

```
  function getcategoryPro(){
 if(isset($_GET['category'])){

$cat_id = $_GET['category'];

// SQL query to interact with info from our database

$get_category_pro = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id =$cat_id";
 if (isset($_GET['sortby'])) {
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
// SQL query to interact with info from our database
if ($sortby == 'pricehilo') {
$get_category_pro = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id =$cat_id ORDER BY price DESC";
}
elseif ($sortby == 'pricelohi') {
$get_category_pro ="SELECT * FROM products WHERE cat_id =$cat_id ORDER BY price ASC";
  }

 }  
 $run_category_pro= mysql_query($get_category_pro); 


   $count = mysql_num_rows($run_category_pro); 

 if($count==0){
  echo"<h2>no Products found in this category!";
            }   

   $dynamicList = '<table border="0" cellpadding="2">';
 while($row_products = mysql_fetch_array($run_category_pro)){ 

   $id = $row_products["id"];
   $product_name = $row_products["product_name"];
   $price=$row_products["price"];
   $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y",strtotime($row_products['date_added']));



   if ($i % 9 == 0) { // if $i is divisible by our target number (in this case "3")
    $dynamicList .= 
    '<tr><td><img style="padding:10px;/><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img 
  style="border: #000033 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" 
  width="200" height="225" alt="' . $product_name . '"/><br/>
      <width="150" align="left" valign="top" scope="col">' . $product_name . '<br/>
      Rs.&nbsp;' . $price . '<br/>
      <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><button>Buy Now</button></td>';


   } else {
    $dynamicList .= '<td><img style="padding:10px;/><a href="product.php?id=' . $id .
  '"><img style="border: #000033 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" 
 width="200" height="225" alt="' . $product_name . '"/><br/>
      <width="150" align="left" valign="top" scope="col">' . $product_name . '<br/>
      Rs.&nbsp;' . $price . '<br/>
      <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><button>Buy Now</button></td>';


    }
   $i++;
  }

  echo $dynamicList;
  $dynamicList .= '</tr></table>';
    }  
     }
    results.php
   <?php 
  getcategoryPro();
   ?>
    <p><a href="results.php?sortby=pricehilo">Price (Highest-Lowest)</a></p>
    <p><a href="results.php?sortby=pricelohi">Price (Lowest-Highest)</a></p>
```

when clicked on mobiles from dropdown menu this link is coming with product

`results.php?category=1`

when we click on high to low this link is opening with msg
no product found in this category

`results.php?sortby=pricelohi`

it should be:

`results.php?category=1&sortby=pricelohi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
getcategoryPro();
if (isset ($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['category'];
} else {
    // you decide
}
?>
<p><a href="results.php?category=<?= $cat_id ?>&sortby=pricehilo">Price (Highest-Lowest)</a></p>
<p><a href="results.php?category=<?= $cat_id ?>&sortby=pricelohi">Price (Lowest-Highest)</a></p>
```

Comment: @rahulJ could you then mark answer as correct one, please? :)

Comment: please check are other question also   inventory_list.php     <tr>
        <td align="right"><strong>Types</strong></td>
        <td><label>
  <script>
              function get_category(typ_id){
                   $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "get_category.php",
                   data: { typ_id : typ_id } 
                   }).done(function(data){
                   $("#category").html(data);
                   });
                   }
        </script>

Comment: <select name="typ_id" id="typ_id" onchange="get_category(this.value)">
     <option>Select a Type</option>
          <?php
  
   $get_types = "select * from types";
   
   $run_types = mysql_query($get_types);
   
   while ($row_types=mysql_fetch_array($run_types)){
   
       $typ_id= $row_types['typ_id'];
    $typ_name = $row_types['typ_name'];
   
    echo "<option value='$typ_id'>$typ_name</option>";
          
    }
      ?>
  </select>  </label></td>
      </tr>

Comment: <tr> <td align="right" id='cat_id'><strong>Category</strong></td> <td><label> <select name="cat_id" id="cat_id"> <option>Select a Category</option> </select> </label></td> </tr>

Answer (score 0):

Just change your links to `<a href="results.php?category=<?php echo $_GET['category']; ?>&sortby=pricehilo">`.